# Catch words by regex in some sentenses

Tags: regex

I want to select the word "Tình yêu" (maybe changed) from all below cases:

```
Tình yêu là gì?
Tình yêu là gì
Tình yêu là gì ?
Tình yêu là cái gì
Tình yêu là cái gì vậy
Tình yêu là cái gì thế
Tình yêu nghĩa là gì
Tình yêu nghĩa là gì vậy
Tình yêu nghĩa là gì thế
Tình yêu nghĩa là cái gì
Tình yêu nghĩa là cái gì vậy
Tình yêu nghĩa là cái gì thế
Tình yêu có nghĩa là gì
Tình yêu có nghĩa là gì vậy
Tình yêu có nghĩa là gì thế
Tình yêu có nghĩa là cái gì
Tình yêu có nghĩa là cái gì vậy
Tình yêu có nghĩa là cái gì thế
```

I used the pattern:

```
(.(?!có|nghĩa|là))( có)?( nghĩa)? là( cái)? gì( vậy)?( thế)?( )?(\?)?
```

or pattern:

```
([^(có|nghĩa|là)]+)( có)?( nghĩa)? là( cái)? gì( vậy)?( thế)?( )?(\?)?
```

but not work.

Please help me, and sorry because I didn't use English in my question.

**Edit**

Thank you for reading my question, I found the solution:

```
(.*(?<!có|nghĩa))( có)?( nghĩa)? là( cái)? gì( vậy)?( thế)?( )?(\?)?
```

Comment: Where will you be using this regex? any programming language or particular text editor?

Comment: I use it in a chatting program between human and computer. All above sentences are questions to the computer. They mean in English: "What's love? (Love = "Tình yêu"). That question can be asked in many ways in my language (Vietnamese), and I want the computer can catch the word and answer to me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll be using PCRE and you want to select occurrences of **Tình yêu** from given text, try following simple regex:

```
/Tình yêu/
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO2dC0/1) here

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully, I wrote the word "Tình yêu" maybe changed to another word, for example: "Thế giới", "Chiến tranh", "Tình tay ba", "Stack Over Flow", "Regular Expression"... Can't use your pattern! My problem is not really simple like that.

Comment: Have you tried another word? just replace with **ình yêu** with whatever you want.

Comment: These word is sent from client side, and at the server side, my code must catch them. Do you understand? I mean these word can be changed by the user, not me, not my program. I don't know what user send to server.